# How can I generate warnings for non internationalized java strings at build time

Tags: java, eclipse, internationalization, teamcity, string-externalization

I am looking for a solution that can be run on a continuous integration server (TeamCity) which seems to rule out IDE specific solutions like the externalization that is built into eclipse.

I need to generate warnings when strings are found in the java source files, unless they have been somehow flagged (by comment or annotation) as not requiring internationalization, eg the // $NON-NLS-1$ comment for eclipse.

The code is built using maven in teamcity.

I have not been able to find existing solutions or any ideas on how a custom solution might be hooked into either maven or teamcity (note I am not hugely familiar with either so could be overlooking something fairly obvious).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need some specifically crafted Static Code Analysis tool.
I am afraid that no such thing exists yet (or I should say no such thing is available for public use...). I am not sure if you would be able to create warnings from the tool though. I know it would be possible with [Gradle](http://gradle.org/), but integrating Gradle task with Java code is not an easiest thing to do (BTDT).

Maybe some simple HTML report would do? In this case, you can simply use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) with regular expressions that matches all the strings literals... That is unless you'll find exclusions (another RegExp) in the same line. That's pretty basic thing to do.

Comment: this certainly looks interesting - my main issue is I have no idea how to hook it into the build process

Comment: @dice: I believe it will be pretty clear after you read [this tutorial](http://www.javabeat.net/writing-a-custom-plugin-for-maven/)